# nginx gzip compression results in larger file sizes

Tags: nginx, gzip

I'm trying to enable compression for a SPA application that is 99% JS and CSS.

Here is the nginx config that I'm using: (I have commented out some settings while testing, but even if enabled do not improve the situation.)

```
gzip on;
# gzip_disable "msie6";
# gzip_vary on;
# gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;    
# gzip_http_version 1.1;    
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype image/svg+xml image/x-icon application/javascript;
```

The resulting file sizes have increased by a tiny bit.

Here is what the browser says:

[image]
[image]

I can't see what the problem is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the antivirus. ESET was doing stuff. Opened a VM and from there everything was OK.

Answer (score 0):

The increase you're seeing is actually just the header overhead, not compression somehow working in reverse. In actuality, your content is not being compressed at all.

If the response were compressed, you would see `content-encoding: gzip` in your response headers.